# How do I convert a path in ASCII hex code, to its equivalent ASCII letters?

Tags: python, path, urlencode

I am trying to use the following path in Python:

*/home/user/Music/library/1-02%2520Maralito.mp3*

The file name is: *"1-02 Maralito.mp3"*

So the space is being converted to the code **%2520**, which I do not know what represents.

I am using Rhythmbox API on Ubuntu, and I can't convert the value back in Python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string has been URL-encoded twice. The `%25` represents a `%` character. The `%20` resulting from decoding the `%25` represents a space.

`urllib.parse.unquote` (just `urllib.unquote` in Python 2) decodes the `%` encoding, and you will want to decode it twice:

```
t = "/home/user/Music/library/1-02%2520Maralito.mp3"
from urllib.parse import unquote   # Python 3
from urllib import unquote         # Python 2
print(unquote(unquote(t)))
```