# Accessing a file where the path contains encoding characters like space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following path:

```
 path='F:\media\owner\166\image\first%20page%20emil.jpg'
```

The file exist in path but I get F

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

I presume because of space, `%20`. I tried `os.path.normpath(path)` but doesn't work. I'm on Windows.

Comment: The correct path is probably `r'F:\media\owner\166\image\first page emil.jpg'`. `%20` is when you have a URL representing the file path. Make sure to use a raw string.

Comment: yes, the url is save for web access

Comment: try adding  `#This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8` line as first line of code file.

Comment: `unquote(path)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “the URL is save for web access” but did you try the suggestion? Also, is the path a literal part of your code or is it something you get from somewhere else?

Comment: Also: [How do I convert a path in ASCII hex code, to its equivalent ASCII letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225615/how-do-i-convert-a-path-in-ascii-hex-code-to-its-equivalent-ascii-letters-in-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `unquote` function from `urllib.parse` like this

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

path = r'F:\media\owner\166\image\first%20page%20emil.jpg'
path = unquote(path)
print(path)
F:\media\owner\166\image\first page emil.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

try this exmple

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
print(unquote("F:\media\owner\166\image\first%20page%20emil.jpg"))
```